# Storing incoming telnet request into a list using twisted

Tags: python, twisted

I want to store http request line from telnet or browser into a list in python.
I am using basic.LineReceiver protocol

Comment: Can you be a little more specific. Are you trying to write a server that can be connected via a browser as well as telnet client or is it ok if you listen to HTTP request on a different port and telnet connection request on different port. It would be nice to understand the usage / requirement further.

Comment: Additionally, it shouldn't matter if you're using basic.LineReceiver or anything else.  `list.append` is `list.append` is `list.append`.

Answer (score 0):

In `YourProtocol.lineReceived()`:

```
if matched(line):
   self.factory.your_list.append(line)
```